# Create an array of objects Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table field which I populate dynamically.

```
 <table id="list" class="table table-striped ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>

  <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Expression</th>
    <th>Variable</th>
    <th>Default</th>
    <th>Date pattern</th>
    <th>Readable</th>
    <th>Writable</th>
    <th>Required</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

I populate it with data I get from a dialog modal.
This is a function I use to populate the table

```
$("#list tbody").append("<tr>"+
            "<td>" + id.val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + name_re.val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + type.val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + expression.val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + variable.val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + defaut.val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + pattern.val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + readable + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + writable + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + required + "</td>" +
            "<td>" +"<button type='button' class='removebutton' title='Remove this propertie'>"+"</button>" +
            "<button type='button' class='editbutton' title='Edit this propertie'>"+"</button>" +
            "<button type='button' class='savebutton' title='save propertie changes'>"+"</button>" +"</td>"+
            "</tr>"
            );
```

Now I created a function to get the data from the table and push them into an array of objects, as each object represent the data of a single row from the table.
This is the function I use to get the data

```
function getPropertiesListData(){
var propertiesList=[];
var id,
type,
expression,
variable,
defaut,
pattern,
readable,
writable,
required, 
name;

$("#list").find('tr').each(function(){
    var $tds=$(this).find('td');
    propertiesList.push({
            id:$tds.eq(0).text();
            name:$tds.eq(1).text();
            type:$tds.eq(2).text();
            expression:$tds.eq(3).text();
            variable:$tds.eq(4).text();
            defaut:$tds.eq(5).text();
            pattern:$tds.eq(6).text();
            readable:$tds.eq(7).text();
            writable:$tds.eq(8).text();
            required:$tds.eq(9).text();

    });
});
return propertiesList;}
```

But when I run, I have this error in the output of the navigator console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

this error is about the line:

```
id:$tds.eq(0).text();
```

Can you  help me to resolve this, or tell me where I'm wrong, or tell me a way to get the data from the table and store them into an array.

Comment: Use `,` to delimit the object properties, not `;`. Closing as a typo.

Comment: Replace the semicolon `;` with a comma `,` in your object.

Comment: Yes, replacing the ; with , resolved my error; Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
propertiesList.push({
            id:$tds.eq(0).text(),
            name:$tds.eq(1).text(),
            type:$tds.eq(2).text(),
            expression:$tds.eq(3).text(),
            variable:$tds.eq(4).text(),
            defaut:$tds.eq(5).text(),
            pattern:$tds.eq(6).text(),
            readable:$tds.eq(7).text(),
            writable:$tds.eq(8).text(),
            required:$tds.eq(9).text(),

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```js
$("#list tbody").append("<tr>"+
            "<td>1</td>" +
            "<td>test</td>" +
            "<td>test-type</td>" +
            "<td>test-expr</td>" +
            "<td>test-val</td>" +
            "<td>test-def</td>" +
            "<td>test-patt</td>" +
            "<td>test-r</td>" +
            "<td>test-w</td>" +
            "<td>test-req</td>" +
            "<td>" +"<button type='button' class='removebutton' title='Remove this propertie'>"+"</button>" +
            "<button type='button' class='editbutton' title='Edit this propertie'>"+"</button>" +
            "<button type='button' class='savebutton' title='save propertie changes'>"+"</button>" +"</td>"+
            "</tr>"
            );
 function getPropertiesListData(){
var propertiesList=[];
var id,
type,
expression,
variable,
defaut,
pattern,
readable,
writable,
required, 
name;

$("#list").find('tr').each(function(){
    var $tds=$(this).find('td');
    propertiesList.push({
            "id":$tds.eq(0).text(),
            "name":$tds.eq(1).text(),
            "type":$tds.eq(2).text(),
            "expression":$tds.eq(3).text(),
            "expression":$tds.eq(4).text(),
            "defaut":$tds.eq(5).text(),
            "pattern":$tds.eq(6).text(),
            "readable":$tds.eq(7).text(),
            "writable":$tds.eq(8).text(),
            "required":$tds.eq(9).text(),

    });
});
return propertiesList;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list" class="table table-striped ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>

  <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Expression</th>
    <th>Variable</th>
    <th>Default</th>
    <th>Date pattern</th>
    <th>Readable</th>
    <th>Writable</th>
    <th>Required</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Himanshu Upadhyay works fine for me, i just deleted the last comma and that works. 
The code that work is:

```
propertiesList.push({
            id:$tds.eq(0).text(),
            name:$tds.eq(1).text(),
            type:$tds.eq(2).text(),
            expression:$tds.eq(3).text(),
            variable:$tds.eq(4).text(),
            defaut:$tds.eq(5).text(),
            pattern:$tds.eq(6).text(),
            readable:$tds.eq(7).text(),
            writable:$tds.eq(8).text(),
            required:$tds.eq(9).text()

    });
```